# How can I build a react-native iOS Application with fastlane

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, react-native, fastlane

I would like to have my (let's say fresh) react-native application build and pushed to apples itunes connect with [fastlane](https://fastlane.tools/), as it seems to be able to have this done in [one task](https://twitter.com/gpblv/status/651701038404268034).
How would a fastlane configuration or generally speaking a project setup would look like?

My main pain points are

- How do I include the minified bundle in the build app
- How do I get the app not to request a localhost port if it is a build version
- How would the provisioning profile stuff and the main configuration look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to do this and wrote a blog post about it: https://weluse.de/blog/react-native-deployment-with-fastlane.html